# Dropdown menu alwways opened

Tags: html, menu, polymer

I'm learning Polymer and I encountered a little problem while doing the menu. Apparently, when I add the dropdown menu it displays opened always, it doesn't close and open at will. Also, I checked the code at the github repo from Polymer and its demos and can't find out what am I doing wrong.

```
          <paper-toolbar>
            <paper-menu-button>
      <paper-icon-button icon="menu" class="dropdown-trigger"></paper-icon-button>
      <paper-menu class="dropdown-content">
        <paper-item>Share</paper-item>
        <paper-item>Settings</paper-item>
        <paper-item>Help</paper-item>
      </paper-menu>
    <paper-menu-button>

</paper-menu-button>
      <div class="title">Title</div>
      <paper-icon-button icon="refresh"></paper-icon-button>
      </paper-toolbar>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are having an extra `<paper-menu-button>` before 
      `</paper-menu-button>
      <div class="title">Title</div>`

This is how your code should looks

```js
<base href="http://polygit.org/polymer+:master/components/">
<script src="webcomponentsjs/webcomponents-lite.min.js"></script>
<link href="polymer/polymer.html" rel="import">

<link href="paper-input/paper-input.html" rel="import">
<link href="paper-slider/paper-slider.html" rel="import">
<link href="paper-toolbar/paper-toolbar.html" rel="import">
<link href="paper-menu/paper-menu.html" rel="import">
<link href="paper-menu-button/paper-menu-button.html" rel="import">
<link href="paper-item/paper-item.html" rel="import">
<link href="paper-icon-button/paper-icon-button.html" rel="import">
  <link rel="import" href="iron-icons/iron-icons.html">

<dom-module id="my-app">
  <template>

    <paper-toolbar>
      <paper-menu-button>
        <paper-icon-button icon="menu" class="dropdown-trigger">+</paper-icon-button>
        <paper-menu class="dropdown-content">
          <paper-item>Share</paper-item>
          <paper-item>Settings</paper-item>
          <paper-item>Help</paper-item>
        </paper-menu>
      </paper-menu-button>

      <div class="title">Title</div>
      <paper-icon-button icon="refresh"></paper-icon-button>
    </paper-toolbar>



  </template>
  <script>
     addEventListener('WebComponentsReady', function() {
      Polymer({
      is: 'my-app',

      properties: {

      }


    }); 

    });
  </script>
</dom-module>
<my-app></my-app>
```

I don't know if you have imported all the required `imports`, but here is a [Plunkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/Kn1tMQFv6630davITQVs?p=preview) , you can see it in action

Comment: to add, i rechecked and everything is imported as far as I know . In plunkr I can't see anything at least with FF

Comment: I updated the code to the full version, in case you can not see the plunkr

Comment: I updated the code in the plunkr, it will work now in firefox, you can check